# .NET 4.0 to 4.5 migration and running on 4.0 machine exception

Tags: c#, .net, migration

I have an C# application which is built on Windows Server 2012 with .NET 4.5. Now as part of the other process another machine needs to run this app.
It's probably using Process.Start to execute my .exe file. I can't say 100% because I don't have access to the code. Everything was fine when it was using .NET 4.0 but now when I've migrated to .NET 4.5 it's throwing an exception:

> The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

I assumed that the problem is that there is no .NET 4.5 installed on this machine so I've removed this line from the config file to support running on .NET 4.0.

```
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/></startup>
```

It still haven't helped and the same exception is being thrown.
My application references another libraries which use 4.5.1 framework but it shouldn't matter. I've read somewhere that they are treated as 4.0 application (4.5 features are not used). The build server has also changed from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012 but it shouldn't matter which OS was used to build, should it? I appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 3):

> The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS
>   platform

Your application should be built using `AnyCPU` platform. If you try to run an application built with `Debug|x64` or `Release|x64` on a 32bit OS, the whole executable won't work and you'll get that error.

### Update

OP said in some comment:

> Issue doesn't seem to be fixed. Does it matter that one of the referenced libraries is forced to use x86 due to C++ references?

Then, you're forced to start the process from a 32bit process.

Comment: My app is built using x86 platform which should be working everywhere. But this settings hasn't been changed after .net 4.5 migration anyway...

Comment: Issue doesn't seem to be fixed. Does it matter that one of the referenced libraries is forced to use x86 due to C++ references?

Comment: @Zbigniew This is another issue too. This will be your last fight.

Comment: yes, so why it is not working now if it worked previously with .NET 4.0 ?

Comment: @Zbigniew I'm sure there's another difference than just switching the framework version that you're not aware of..

Comment: thank you for your help, I'll investigate it further.

Comment: I've just removed all the references from the app which is executed switched to 4.0 -> working, switched to 4.5 -> getting that exception. So .NET is the cause of the problems but where may be problem on the machine which is invoking it? It has 3.5 or 4.0 installed but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Now I need to go. BTW, if you encounter any useful info to identify the issue, comment out here again

Comment: I'll try but without base code it's very hard to find the problem.